# rails linkto_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i want to implement a digg-like vote up/down method in my rails application using ajax. and i found that link_to_remote can do just that. but i want to check whether there's already a vote by the current user so that no user can vote up twice or more. how can i do that - how can i return values based on some condition so that an forbidden vote action triggers link_to_remote :failure condition??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the HTTP status code appropriately (not in the 200 range, you probably want 403 (forbidden, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) unless you handle that separately in your app -- it doesn't really matter what the code is, just that it's not in 200 range).

To set the status code, in your render line, you add

```
:status => 403
```

It seems like you are all set for the rest of this (i.e., specifying and implementing the failure condition, etc. etc.)